# Pandas DF Index column causing issues in Selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I am attempting to automate a browser submission using Python and Selenium, part of this involves reading in a csv file and parsing these parameters into the browser element IDs - the problem is, the dataframe is attempting to parse the index column as part of any of the columns I am submitting - the main problem is affecting the text drop down fields.

Here is my read_csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxx\xxx.csv', sep=';', dtype=str)
```

when running a `print(df.Color)` it gives me:

```
0        Blue
```

I then set a variable called color: `Color = df.Color`

My selenium variable parse looks like this:

```
Select(driver.find_element("id", "color")).select_by_visible_text(Color)
```

The error I receive is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: 0    Blue
```

This does not happen to any of the free text fields - they work perfectly but the select drop down is the issue - any advice?

Comment: Try `Color = df.Color.iat[0]`

Comment: Thank you .iat[0] worked 100%

Comment: I do not believe the duplicate proposed is the same issue I was facing - that is a float type issue - this was related to a index causing issues in selenium itself, and even though iat and iloc can accomplish the same thing the issue faced is not the same

Comment: Solution is for convert one element Series to scalar, type of value is not important - should be float, int, string, datetime...